# linq to object getting the correct pattern

Tags: c#, string, linq, linq-to-objects

i have my records as follows

```
mazhar-kaunain-baig-5
mazhar-kaunain-baig-5-6
mazhar-kaunain-baig
```

this is my query

```
ptype = _pagecontext.PagesRefs
                    .Where(m => m.nvcr_Slug.Contains(str+ "-") && m.bit_Active == true)
                    .ToList();
```

***correct results:***

```
 1) str=mazhar-kaunain-baig
```

bring back

```
mazhar-kaunain-baig-5
mazhar-kaunain-baig-5-6   

 2) str=mazhar-kaunain
```

bring back nothing

```
 3) str=mazhar
```

bring back nothing

the contains and equals becomes invalid in this scenario . how could i achieve the following result where i have the exact matching of the pattern.

Comment: Can't help unless you define the pattern that is acceptable.  Is it always that that "mazhar-kaunain-baig" should return all matches when the string is followed by one of more "-[digit]"s?  Can multiple digits follow a dash - is "mazhar-kaunain-baig-24" valid?  My guess is that you want to match `m.nvcr_Slug` against some type of regular expression, but we don't have enough information yet.  Also, you don't need the `== true` in `m.bit_Active == true`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

take out  the `+"-"`?

`sRefs.Where(m => m.nvcr_Slug.Contains(str) && m.bit_Active == true).ToList();`

Comment: feeling embarassed i have to ask this, you exactly knew what was going on in my head. need to take a break or so now i guess. thanks

Comment: This fails tests 2 & 3, at least as I understand it.

Comment: But i think the problem was not with +"-"

Comment: Yeah, that's also what I understand. I thought that in 2 and 3 the result should be nothing.

Answer (score 0):

why don't you use `StartsWith` instead ?

*Determines whether the beginning of this string instance matches the specified string.*

```
.Where(m => m.nvcr_Slug.StartsWith(str) && m.bit_Active == true).ToList();
```

more info at:

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/baketfxw.aspx

Answer (score 0):

This will return the exact results you mentioned in situation 1, 2 and 3.

```
var result = from d in data
             let remainingString = d.Slug.Remove(0, Math.Min(text.Length + 1, d.Slug.Length))
             where remainingString.Length > 0 && Char.IsDigit(remainingString[0])
             select d;
```